# JSP JAVA: Illegal start of type try-catch

Tags: java, jsp, try-catch

I've looked at several posts pertaining to the same problem I'm having but I can't figure out how to fix mine. They say to add a public class but I'm just met with more errors. I get an error at line 1 which is a comment that is fine before I add the try-catch. (Code skips to where try catch is)

```
<%      

    String curr1 = request.getParameter("lstCurrency1");
    String curr2 = request.getParameter("lstCurrency2");
    String errorMessage = null;

    try {
    Double currIn = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txtCurrency1"));            
    Double convert = fxDataModel.getFxRate(curr1,curr2)*currIn;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){ 
        errorMessage = "Please insert a valid number!";
    }
    String[] currencies = fxDataModel.getFxCurrencies(); 
%>
```

This code is above my html page which draws on currIn and convert to fill textboxes. Everything here works fine until I add the try-catch. I have read that I might need to add a public class but everytime I try it gives me more errors and "request" is no longer recognized. Could anyone help me figure out why it's saying Illegal start of type?

Thanks

Comment: Please copy the exact error message you get.

Comment: @Henry I get "illegal start of type" and my variables currIn and convert become underlined and say "cannot find symbol" later in my html

Comment: 1) The code you posted appears correct.  So there's probably important stuff *YOU'RE NOT SHOWING US*!!!! 2) You cannot declare "currIn" and "convert" *inside* the try/catch block.  This probably explains the "undefined" error (again - it doesn't look like you posted the code that gave the actual error).  3) It's a bad idea to use try/catch blocks in JSP (hence the advice to "add a class") ... but it's NOT ILLEGAL, and it's NOT THE PROBLEM.  You need to post the exact code giving "Illegal start of type", and also post the EXACT MESSAGE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare variables in a `try` block therefore they can only be used in the block.

Therefore put the declaration outside of the try-block:

```
Double currIn = null, convert = null;
try {
    currIn = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txtCurrency1"));            
    convert = fxDataModel.getFxRate(curr1,curr2)*currIn;
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex){ 
    errorMessage = "Please insert a valid number!";
}
```

Comment: Yup, emailed my professor for help and he said the same thing, nice catch even though I mistakenly didn't post all the code needed. Thank you!